# How to give input parameters value while calling the function[VI.Call()] as well?

Tags: python, labview

1. I'm trying to Control LabVIEW front panel in python using by ActiveX 
   communication.
2. I couldn't assign the input parameter values automatically in LabVIEW.
3. If I run as follows program code it's assigning as 'zero' for both 
   inputs(Input 1, Input 2).
4. Whenever I tried to run the program the controls taking as default value.
5. Is there any method for assigning input values while the VI.Call() function(calling and value assigning should happen simultaneously)?.
6. Give a conclusion for this issue.

I tried VI.Call() function after set input values and the LabVIEW VI taking input values as 'zero'(0).

```
import win32com.client                                      # ActivX Client
LabVIEW = win32com.client.Dispatch("LabVIEW.Application")   # Connect LabVIEW
VI = LabVIEW.getVIReference(r'D:\New folder\LabVIEW.py')    # Get VI Reference
VI._FlagAsMethod('Call')                                    # Call the VI
VI.Call()
VI.setcontrolvalue('Input 1', '56')                         # Set Input Value
VI.setcontrolvalue('Input 2', '10')                         # Set Input Value
result = VI.getcontrolvalue('out')                          # Get Output Value
print(result)                                               # Print result on console
```

I expecting input values to be 56 and 53, but the actual inputs are 0 and 0(automatically assigning in LabVIEW as default).

[Simple Addition Pgm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV5vh.png)

Comment: `LabVIEW.getVIReference(r'D:\New folder\LabVIEW.py')`

Is this the correct path for the VI? I'm just noting the .py extension.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that its correct path.

Comment: Can you show us your VI's block diagram? It looks as if you run the VI with `VI.Call()` before you set the input values.

Comment: As you asked I've edited my post with LabVIEW VI image #Simple Addition Pgm. Let me know, If any concerns?

Answer (score 0):

The call() already executes the VI, so setting its controls after is too late. Set them first, then run call().

I'm also pretty sure the call method waits for the VI to terminate, so setting the controls after makes even less sense.

Even if it does not wait, the VI might already have started to process the control values before you set them. In this case, you might also read out the result indicator before the vi has written the result to it, i.e. You somehow have to wait for the vi to complete before reading the result.

### Update:

I tried myself, and added some debugging. This python code shows start and stop time, and sets the controls to random values:

```
import win32com.client                                      # ActivX Client
from datetime import datetime
import random

a=random.randint(0,100)
b=random.randint(0,100)
c=a+b

LabVIEW = win32com.client.Dispatch("LabVIEW.Application")   # Connect LabVIEW
VI = LabVIEW.getVIReference(r'D:\lvTest.vi')                # Get VI Reference
print "Call: ",datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
VI._FlagAsMethod('Call')                                    # Call the VI

VI.setcontrolvalue('Input 1', a)                            # Set Input Value
VI.setcontrolvalue('Input 2', b)                            # Set Input Value

VI.Call()

result = VI.getcontrolvalue('out')                          # Get Output Value

print "Done: ",datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
print " %d + %d = %d.  LV result: %f   Equal: %s"%(a,b,c,result, result==c)
```

I also added some logging to the VI, but let it write it to a file:

[image]

For me, this works always, regardless if LV is open or not.

**Except...** when the VI is reentrant (Properties -> Execution). In this case, the VI always reads 0 from its controls, and writes 0 to its indicator. Even if it writes something else, Python will read back the default value of this indicator (0 if not changed)

This *is somewhat expected*! When a reentrant VI should be executed, a new instance (copy) of it is created in memory, which is then executed. If your VI is reentrant, python opens it, sets the values correctly, but when its executed, a new instance with default values is created and executed. When it terminates, python reads the result from the original instance, which did never run.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve this problem here.

Comment: Hello sweber,                                                                                                          
Even I've been tried the same logic , where VI.call() executes after assigning inputs. But it doesn't working. And regardless of LV open it'd works me too.  I agree the VI reentrant(Properties >> Execution), in this case the VI aways return o from its control (as we know it's default). The thing is python datum shall to be reflect in LabVIEW input controls.

Comment: VI.Call() resets input controls to default for me but VI.Run() works as expected after VI.setcontrolvalue calls. The VI I am calling is not re-entrant. And you have to use VI._FlagAsMethod('Run') prior to using the VI.Run() method otherwise errors out.

Answer (score 0):

VI.Call() resets input controls to default for me but VI.Run() works as expected after VI.setcontrolvalue calls. The VI I am calling is not re-entrant. And you have to use VI._FlagAsMethod('Run') prior to using the VI.Run() method otherwise errors out.